# ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized. while im using abstract class connection

Tags: c#, ado.net

Here i'm using connection state in abstract class

```
  public abstract class Connection
    {
        private static string _Connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTXDB"].ConnectionString;
 public static string GetConnection{ get { return _Connection; }}
}
    public abstract void ProcessConnection();
```

This class i implemented in Another class(BusinessConnection.cs)

```
 public class BusinessClass :Connection
    {
     public override void ProcessConnection()
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.GetConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
            }
```

Now i called this Class(BusinessConnection.cs) In my controller as

```
     BusinessClass objcon = new BusinessClass();   
  public IHttpActionResult Index()
                    objcon.ProcessConnection();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee");
//Here how can i inject my Connection in cmd
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (rdr.HasRows == true)
```

Comment: With that `using` statement, you immediatly close the connection again. You need to export the connection so that you can pass it to the command `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select...", conn);`

Comment: @ReneVogt could u plz help me how can i overcome this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a little design flaw. You obviously want to use the connection outside the `BusinessClass`/`Connection` classes.

So maybe you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class Connection
{
    public abstract SqlConnection OpenConnection();

    // your code
}
```

and in your `BusinessClass`:

```
public override SqlConnection OpenConnection()
{
     var conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.GetConnection))
     conn.Open();
     return conn;
}
```

And then in your querying code:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = objcon.OpenConnection())
{
    // create SqlCommand and pass conn!
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
        // and the rest of your rdr reading code
        }
    }
}
```

The `using` statements take care of closing/disposing the respective objects.

Comment: Sorry 2 say like this Is This a Standard methode? Or do we need any thing to implement?

Comment: @MdGhousemohi What do you mean? The constructor taking the `conn`? It's standard. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MdGhousemohi As you can see in the documentation, you can also set `cmd.Connection = conn;`

Comment: using(SqlConnection conn = objcon.CreateConnection())
{Here im Getting Cant Implecity convert void to system.data.sql

Comment: @MdGhousemohi ahh sorry, I mixed the naming...I meant `OpenConnection()`, the method I declared above. Fixed my answer.

Comment: public override SqlConnection OpenConnection()
{
     var conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.GetConnection))
     conn.Open();
}    not all code implement?

Comment: @MdGhousemohi Obviously I forgot the `return` statement. Fixed it.

Comment: Vogt Thannnnnkkkss aaa lot